# import large excel file into Mysql DB using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

Dear "never give up" fellow,

After 3 weeks trying to find out a solution, I give up and request your assistance on the following.

I am trying to create a mysql db (done), a table (done) and import an excel file into the created DB (failed) using python (I could use workbench but I decided I must do it in python)

the code is available here (hope it works as this is the first time I use github) 
https://github.com/LucTiber/GLBPRS20200412/tree/master 
 The error I am getting is :

TypeError: "<" not supported between instances of "str" and "float" error message in full can be found on the git page too

I review both the raw and transformed files and could not find any string ...

Any clue is more then welcome

Side note for those who are prompt to -1 : we are all trying to learn by trying and sometimes it means asking for help from more skillful and ready to share. So be open minded and ready to help. Thanks !

Comment: Try to provide an [mre] and also include your code in the post as it increases visibility for others searching for the same problem

Comment: Hi Bjorn B, may I suggest you connect to the GitHub page (everything is there). If you cannot access for any reason just let me know. will be very much obliged to accomodate

Comment: Are you aware Pandas has a [`DataFrame.sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method to push a data frame directly to database table? Also, not sure why you need to use Excel methods and not values directly from Pandas data frame.

Comment: No I was not Parfait. Thanks for expanding my options. I am relatively new and since this is not my core expertise, I try to learn on cas by case basis. To answer the second question, I am exporting data from servicenow and since I use to manipulate these thru excel it was making more sense to me. I will have a look into the proposed method but for my knowledge I am still very much interested in why this error occurred (stubborn =yes definitely;-))

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out why it was note working 
MySQL does not like empty dates even if empty is allowed

Fill the empty cells with fake dates like 12/21/2999 and it should work